# Making AJAX Applications Crawlable? How to build a simple web service on Google App Engine to produce HTML Snapshots?

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, seo, htmlunit

**Real World Problem:**

I have my app hosted on [Heroku](http://heroku.com/), who (to my knowledge) are unable to offer a solution for running a Headless (GUI-less) Browser - such as [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) - for generating [HTML Snapshots](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html) for Googlebot to index my AJAX content.

**My Proposed Solution:**

*If you haven't already, I suggest reading Google's [Full Specification for Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html).*

Imagine I have:

- a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) app hosted on Heroku on the domain `http://example.com`
- the app has tabs along the top of the page **TabA, TabB and TabC**
- under each tab is **SubTab1, SubTab2, SubTab3**
- onload if the url is `http://example.com#!tab=TabA&subtab=SubTab3` then client-side Javascript takes the `location.hash` and loads in TabA, SubTab3 content via AJAX.

*Note: the Hash Bang (#!) is part of the [google spec](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).*

I would like to build a simple "web service" hosted on [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) (GAE) that:

1. Accepts a URL param e.g. `http://htmlsnapshot.appspot.com?url=http://example.com#!tab=TabA&subtab=SubTab3` (url param should be URLEncoded)
2. Runs HTMLUnit to open `http://example.com#!tab=TabA&subtab=SubTab3` and run the client-side javascript on the sever.
3. HTMLUnit returns the DOM once everything is complete (or something like 45 seconds has passed).
4. The return content could be sent back via JSON/JSONP, or alternatively a URL is return to a file generated and stored on the google app engine server (for file based "cached" results)... open to suggestions here. If a URL to a file was returned then you could [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to get the source code (aka a HTML Snapshot).

My `http://example.com` app would need to manage the call to `http://htmlsnapshot.appspot.com`... basically:

1. Catch Googlebots call to `http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=tab=TabA%26subtab=SubTab3` (googlebot crawler escapes certain characters e.g. %26 = &).
2. Send request from the backend to `http://htmlsnapshot.appspot.com?url=http://example.com#!tab=TabA&subtab=SubTab3` (url param should be URLEncoded)
3. Render the returned HTML Snapshot to the frontend.
4. Google Indexes the content and we rejoice!

I don't have any experience with Google App Engine or Java or HTMLUnit.

I might be able to figure it out... and will post my results if I do.

Otherwise I feel this is a **VERY good opportunity** for someone to write a kick-ass blog post that outlines **a novices step-by-step guide** to setting up a web service like this.

This will introduce more people to the excellent (and free!) Google App Engine. Also it will undoubtably encourage more people to adopt Google's specs for crawlable AJAX content... something we can all benefit from!

As Google's specification gains more acceptance the "hurdle" of setting up a Headless Browser is going to send **many** devs Googling for answers! Get in now with an answer for fame and glory! (edit: at the very least I will sing your praises).

**Hit me up on twitter `@_chrisjacob` if you would like to discuss solutions.**

Comment: Interesting read: "Get HtmlUnit to run on Google App Engine (GAE)" http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2962074&group_id=47038&atid=448269

Comment: See htmlunit 2.8 release notes.

Comment: htmlunit 2.8 release notes: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.8 - you're right they state that GAE support is functional (or at least "fixed").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used HTMLunit on AppEngine. My GWT code to do this is available in the [gwt-platform project](http://gwtplatform.com/) the results I got were similar to that of the [HTMLunit-AppEngine test application](http://ajax-crawler.appspot.com/) by Amit Manjhi.

It should be relatively easy to use GWTP current HTMLunit support to do exactly what you describe, although you could likely do it in a simpler app. One problem I see is that AppEngine requests have a 30 second timeout, so you can't have a page that takes HTMLunit longer than that to process.

**UPDATE**:
It's been a while, but I finally closed the long standing issue about making GWT applications crawlable using GWTP. The documentation is not entirely there, but check out the issue:
  http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=1

Comment: I still have a problem accessing my own application with HTMLunit, which makes it hard for an app to serve itself to the crawler. The details of my issue are subtle but I describe them here (http://bit.ly/bViIMr). I haven't tested this in a while, so maybe the problem went away.

Comment: On Amit Manjhi's test app it seems to work fine with the same URL. Maybe this has fixed itself, or maybe it depends on a multitude of factors.

Comment: Could be. I wondered for a while if it wasn't some limitation of the free AppEngine account that wouldn't spawn two Servlets in frequent succession.

Comment: Thanks Philippe and Matt. I will investigate GWTP and see what results I can come up with. If either of you are interested in working with me on this I think a Headless Brower as a Web Service is an interesting project (and shouldn't be very hard with GAE and GWTP). Today I've been spec'ing out my own solution for building crawlable, accessible, deeplinked AJAX web apps. Leveraging a Headless Browser to generate HTML Snapshots when the client does not have javascript.. "Headless AJAX" I think I'll call it ;). More info soon.

Comment: Chris, there is an open issue on GWTP regarding a module to make App Engine based GWTP apps crawlable. It's blocked on the bug I described above but my latest idea, following the proposal here, is to cut the Gordian knot by providing an easy way to build your own Web Service. Maybe you'd like to contribute on this? (Issue and discussion is at: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=1)