# Can you deploy Watir on Heroku to generate HTML Snapshots? If so, how?

Tags: hosting, heroku, watir, googlebot, headless-browser

**I would like to generate HTML Snapshots using [Watir](http://watir.com/), hosted on [Heroku](http://heroku.com/).**

> > Google's [Full Specification for Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) suggests using [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)... see [How do I create an HTML snapshot?](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html) point #3.

HtmlUnit is a Java-only headless browser emulator; and unfortunately jRuby is not an option on Heroku. So HtmlUnit is ruled out (to my knowledge).

If you're interested I have another question open regarding HtmlUnit as a service hosted on Google App Engine...
[Making AJAX Applications Crawlable? How to build a simple web service on Google App Engine to produce HTML Snapshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517944/making-ajax-applications-crawlable-how-to-build-a-simple-web-service-on-google-a/3572028#3572028) ... still waiting on a proven example/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need a full desktop environment to run watir. Heroku doesn't provide you with that.

You could use a service such as Amazon EC2

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can

Use Watir with PhantomJS, which is headless

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
```

To use PhantomJS on Heroku, you'll need to use a [Heroku PhantomJS buildpack](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs)

Answer (score 3):

Troelskin's answer is incorrect. There are ways to run "headless" browsers with Watir, which do not require a "full desktop environment". Having said that, I do not know which method may be appropriate on Heroku.

Other "headless" automation options (if you are using Ruby) are Mechanize with Open-Uri, along with (optional) Nokogiri.