# GWT Activities and Places and SEO

Tags: gwt, seo

Does GWT2.1 Activities and Places do any changes due to SEO resident GWT problem??

Comment: See related question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430244/making-gwt-application-crawlable-by-a-search-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities and places will make it easier for the user to navigate in your GWT application but search engines will still have the ajax "reading" limitations.

Here are good articles to learn more about [Places](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-places) and [Activities](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-activities)