# filter not executing on static content request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlet-filters

I'm [trying](http://crawlablegwt.appspot.com/) to implement [making gwt apps crawlable](http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/10/12/How_to_Make_Google_AppEngine_Applications_Ajax_Crawlable), but the CrawlFilter isn't being executed, ever. What am I doing wrong? Is static content not subject to filters?

```
<web-app>
  <!-- Crawling servlet filter -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>AjaxCrawlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.bitdual.server.CrawlServlet</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AjaxCrawlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430244/making-gwt-application-crawlable-by-a-search-engine/2432953

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static content is served from an entirely different infrastructure (like a CDN) so I wouldn't be surprised if filters are not executed on content hosted statically.

Comment: Correct. Static content requests never reach your Java app.

Comment: renamed index.html to index.jsp and the filter is being executed. performance implications be damned!